Why can't I turn right and move forwards with two characters at once?
I'm a beginner to unity and just copied the code from someone so I don't fully understand it, but I don't understand what's wrong. I am making a small game with two players. The only code I have is making the characters move, but here is the problem: when I press to move forward and right at the same time with both characters, the last input simply won't work. It only happens with those two directions.
Here is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float m_speed, rotatespeed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                player.velocity = transform.forward * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                player.velocity = -transform.forward * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, -rotatespeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, rotatespeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}

And:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float m_speed2, rotatespeed2;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.I))
            {
                player.velocity = transform.forward * m_speed2 * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.K))
            {
                player.velocity = -transform.forward * m_speed2 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, -rotatespeed2 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.L))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, rotatespeed2 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}

I simply don't know what I can do and any advice would be helpful. );
I have looked trough the code but I have no idea what's wrong.

Is this helpful: Reading two Characters in C# ?

Your scripts look fine, it might be a problem with your keyboard- most only support a certain number of simultaneous inputs. Try inputting the same key combination into a keyboard rollover test; if some of the pressed keys don't appear on the screen, then it's just your keyboard. For example, if I hold A+D on my work keyboard, I cannot input J at all.

@ipodtouch0218 Thank you, you were right! I simply can't press all four of those buttons at once. (:

You can try to find a WASD-like combination that doesn't conflict with one another, support more input methods (one keyboard, one controller?), or just require a keyboard with higher rollover. Regardless, I've moved my comment to an actual answer since it solved your question.

Why are we handling W + S in FixedUpdate but A + D in Update?  I find this greatly distracting.

Besides this probably being more a hardware issue ... why implement two basically equal scripts? As a tip for the future: implement only one script and rather expose fields to configure which inputs you want to bind to -> this cuts maintenance into half and even enables to have even more instances for more players without having to replicate more even more scripts ... And another side effect you could even runtime customize the inputs

Your scripts look fine, it might be a problem with your keyboard- most only support a certain number of simultaneous inputs. Try inputting the same key combination into a keyboard rollover test; if some of the pressed keys don't appear on the screen, then it's just your keyboard. (For example, if I hold A+D on my work keyboard, I cannot input J at all.)
If it is your keyboard, you might have to add support for multiple input devices (such as one player using a keyboard and one using a controller), or just ignore this and have the game only work consistently with a higher-rollover keyboard.

Copied from the comments, since this solved your problem

for information and for searchability, this phenomenon is also called "key ghosting" https://www.microsoft.com/applied-sciences/projects/anti-ghosting-demo/
